# Prove that any natural number can be written as the sum of $n$ different powers of two (starting from $2^0$) each one multiplied by either 0 or 1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binary

Alternative problem statement:

Prove that any natural number can be written as $$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_{i} 2^i$$ if $ a_{i}\in[0, 1]$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Further information:

$a_{i}$ is NOT a constant. $a_{i}$ can take any integer value within the interval $[0, 1]$ (zero or one) at choice for every $i$ (with $0 \leq i \leq n$ and both $i, n \in \mathbb{N}$). We include the zero inside $\mathbb{N}$ when mentioning the natural numbers' set.

Generalization of previous problem:

Prove that any natural number can be written as $$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_{i} b^i$$ if $a_{i} \in [0, b-1]$ at choice per every $i$ and if $b-2, n, i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This is basically converting to base 2. (or binary)

Comment: What did you try about it ?. MSE people is expecting that to write a nice answer.

Comment: I know it is basically converting to base 2, that's why I put "binary" on the tags. I just don't know how to prove it's true. By the way, I have just corrected the bounds (from [0, 2] to [0, 1]), so I would like a moderator of MSE to lift the mark as off topic now that is correctly phrased.

Comment: The question wasn't placed on hold because you didn't phrase a minor point correctly. It was placed on hold because you included zero context for the question: You didn't explain what you tried, what you're having trouble with, where you encountered this problem, or anything else. This is *not* an appropriate place to copy-paste a homework style problem and have it done for you.

Comment: I didn't know that was necessary. Well, it is not homework as I came up with the question myself when thinking about the binary code. I tried to solve it without success, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

For 0, we just need $a_0 = 0$. For 1, $a_0 = 1$ suffices.

Let's call the positive number to be represented $m_0$.

Choose $n$ such that $2^n \leq m_0 < 2^{n + 1}$. Now compute $m_1 = m_0 - 2^n$ and assign $a_n = 1$. What do we know about $m_1$? Only that it is less than $n$. It can have any value from 0 to $2^n - 1$. If $m_1 > 0$, then we can find some power of 2 just like we did for $m_0$, but the exponent will be smaller than $n$. We can just keep repeating this process until eventually winding up with 0. And if we keep track of the $a_i$, we have the binary representation of $m_0$, which is what almost all computers today use to represent non-negative integers.

I'm not sure if you correctly notated the interval. Since $2 \times 2^\alpha = 2^{\alpha + 1}$, assigning $a_i = 2$ would be inefficient at best, an algorithmic error at worst.

Comment: Please consider not writing such a complete answer to a question phrased in this manner (that is, clearly copy-pasted from a homework assignment with not thoughts or efforts on the part of the asker). You may be robbing them of a valuable opportunity to actually *think* about their problem.

Comment: That is untrue. The "advanced students" part was merely a joke. I came up with the question myself when I was thinking about the binary code, and then I generalized the problem to any base.

Comment: @T.Bongers The question originally said "0, 1 or 2." That detail alone convinces me that this is not a copy-and-paste from a textbook. As originally written, the question gave me the impression the asker had actually *thought* about the question but was on the wrong track.

Comment: @RobertSoupe Yes, only time after thinking more thoroughly about this I found that it was absurd to include 2 inside the a_{i} interval, since it would be would equal to the next power of 2, multiplied by 1. As I have said, I came up with the question myself. You can also tell it by the edit logs: I changed the phrasing as I found my own errors.